# Performance gain for functional style in Dart

Tags: performance, functional-programming, dart

Should I expect performance gains for using a purely functional style (without side effects) in Dart? Naively I'd expect the opposite, but I'm imagining there might be more opportunity for optimization.

To give an example, imagine a vector class that could be implemented like so:

```dart
class Vec {
  final num x, y, z;
  Vec(this.x, this.y, this.z);
  Vec add(Vec v) => new Vec(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
}
final x = new Vec(1,2,3).add(new Vec(4,5,6));
```

vs an implementation like this:

```dart
class Vec {
  num x, y, z;
  Vec(this.x, this.y, this.z);
  Vec add(Vec v) { x += v.x; y += v.y; z += v.z; return this; }
}
var x = new Vec(1,2,3).add(new Vec(4,5,6));
```

which creates one less `Vec` object. (Obviously there could be an `add(x,y,z)` method to create still one fewer `Vec` but I'm imagining the added vectors as not being constant values in real life.)

In the Javascript VM, as I understand it, the extra object creation is relatively expensive and you'd rather not create new objects when you don't have to. If this were C++, I'd expect a lot of Vec objects would be on the stack and I'd expect any difference between these two to get optimized away.

I suppose the major optimizability gain of a pure functional style is parallelism, which probably doesn't apply to the Dart VM.

Comment: Why don't you profile it?

Comment: I thought maybe someone would already know. If no one does, I will.

Comment: In general these sorts of questions tend to be moderately complex, except in relation to things which are specifically optimised for. You could also read what the implementers say about their choice of optimisations.

Answer (score 1):

In Dart using an operator is just like calling a method. There is no performance overhead due to implicit operand conversion.

I believe the VM is pretty good an unboxing simple objects and keeping them on the stack, especially where all of the members are final. So for hot code there shouldn't be extra pressure on the garbage collector due to the extra object created.

But like Marcin says - best way to know for sure is to profile this.

Perhaps have a look at the [Tracer benchmark](https://www.dartlang.org/performance/) source code (It's a simple raytracer). I'm pretty sure this uses operator overloading for it's 3D points and vectors. This will give you an idea about javascript vs Dart performance. You could even remove the + operator calls and replace them with an add() method to see if there is much difference. (This is probably more useful than trying to create a micro-benchmark).

Also - perhaps you should change the title of this question - this is not about [pure functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional). Although Dart has a bunch of functional style methods such as map() and fold() it doesn't support pure functional programming as it does not support proper tail calls, which means pure functional programs would cause stack overflows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's technically possible to programme in a pure functional style without tail elimination, it's just unpleasant because the programmer has to handle the lack thereof. Also, for bounded problems a pure functional style is achievable without e.g. trampolining.

Comment: Sure it's possible - as long as you're careful about the stack, and sprinkle Future((_){...}) calls around. But in reality even for tiny programs this is going to be a nightmare to code. Now I wrote "[Dart] doesn't **support** pure functional programming". Can you think of a better way to describe this?

Comment: I thought what I'm talking about does fit the definition of "purely functional", specifically applied to the example I give, not necessarily (or even, necessarily not) applied to the whole program. Declaring the data members x, y and z to be final excludes the possibility of updates, does it not?

Comment: I'm not at all meaning to talk about the operator overloading aspect. I'll edit the question to get rid of it, which I think will make the question clearer.

Comment: I also removed some of the "pure" talk and clarified.

Comment: I'd stick with the immutable Vec implementation (The first one). Both the VM and dart2js should be smart enough to handle this - i.e. unbox to use integers on the stack. If in doubt have a look at the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I went ahead and ran a quick test. Basically I just called added a billion vectors according to each implementation. The functional one took around three times as long. So it seems like, currently, at least, the object creation isn't optimized away.

```dart
void main() {
  const N = 1000000000;
  int i = 0;
  var v = new Vec(0,0,0);
  while (i < N * 3) {
    v = v.add(new Vec(i++, i++, i++));
  }
  print('$v');
}
```

I also tried an implementation with semantics like `add(num,num,num)`, rather than `add(new Vec(num,num,num))`, eliminating another temporary object. That's even faster, but only marginally so; leading me to believe that the compiler *does* manage to partially optimize away that particular temporary object creation.

Comment: These type of micro-benchmarks can give very misleading results. I imagine if you gave a similar benchmark to gcc -O3, it would be reduced to a single print call and throw away the entire loop - as it can infer the value of v. You might want to check on the mailing list.

Comment: Here are some [slides](http://mrale.ph/talks/lxjs2013/) from a talk about micro-benchmarking from a V8/Dart VM developer.

Comment: Point taken, and thanks for the link. And this is one of the reasons I didn't want to profile it myself. But on the other hand I am hoping to find whether the optimizer is capable of such things, which maybe I did. And I'm not keen to implement everything twice to truly profile it if I can avoid it. It does seem to me unlikely that the functional style gives some hoped-for performance benefit at this time.